# Make a circular badge with a border curl over using only CSS?

Tags: css

Is it possible to make a badge curl over like the image below using only CSS?

The text must stay under the curl and gradient as below and the text should be selectable.

[image]

**JS fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/jitendravyas/vVeME/1/

Comment: What've you tried? What failed, or went wrong? What difficulties have you had, or are you having..?

Comment: Do you mean solely in CSS (ie without the use of background-image's)?

Comment: mwan - yes with css pure

Comment: That would be some epic CSS if you got that to work

Comment: Maybe with css mask. but I don't think worth it http://www.webkit.org/blog/181/css-masks/   Also change your border radius to 50% to create a circle

Comment: CSS is not a drawing program and shouldn't be treated as one.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well this is the best I could do :P

http://jsfiddle.net/ree2Z/

Of course it won't work on anything other than a white background, but it's close. XD

Comment: lol thanks @Jleagle but I'm certain it could be done better. :P